# Exception ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite

Tags: oracle

I am getting **`error message`**

```
Exception ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
```

I have created few object type-
which has the composite collection types

```
create TYPE obj1 IS OBJECT
            (vn_count_num        NUMBER,            
             vv_data             VARCHAR2(10000));

create TYPE tab1 IS TABLE OF obj1;

create TYPE obj2 IS OBJECT
            (num         NUMBER,            
             obj1      tab1);

create TYPE tab2 IS TABLE OF obj2;
```

Got Exception ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite 
while running the below block.

what need to done to run the below block successfully

```
declare
  --var1 tab1 := tab1();
  var2 tab2 := tab2();
begin

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINe('Start ');

  --var2.obj1 := tab1();
  var2.extend;
  var2(1).obj1 := tab1();

  var2(1).num:=1;

  var2(1).obj1.extend;

  var2(1).obj1(1).vn_count_num:=1;
  var2(1).obj1(1).vv_data:='Data';


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINe('End ');

exception
  when others then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINe('Exception  '||SQLERRM);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The call of `extend` adds another entry (or slot, if you will) to the array, but the value of this entry is null. So, `var2(1).num := 1` is effectively `cast (null as obj2).num := 1` which throws the excpetion you got.

In order to make the script work, you must explicitly fill the entry with an initialized value, for example like so:

```
declare
  var1 tab1 := tab1();
  var2 tab2 := tab2();
begin

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINe('Start ');
  --var2:=tab2();
  --var1:=tab1();

  var2.extend;

  var2(1) := obj2(null, null);        --       ADD THIS and...
  var2(1).num:=1;

  var1.extend;
  var1(1) := obj1(null, null);        --    ...THIS too

  var1(1).vn_count_num:=1;
  var1(1).vv_data:='Data';

  var2(1).obj1:=var1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINe('End ');

exception
  when others then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINe('Exception  '||SQLERRM);

end;
/
```